# Import only specific cells from Excel to R by hard coding

Tags: r, excel

I have around 100 equal .xls files containing 10 sheets each, with very messy data, here is a thought example of one sheet:

[image]

I want to add everything together in one R dataframe/tibble.

I don't know the right approach here, but I believe that I can hard code this within readxl::read.xls. It should look like this

[image]

I would like if somebody could show a short code of how to pick a cell to be the column name by its position and the data belonging to that column, also by its position/range.

Afterwards, I will find a way to loop this to all sheets within all files, or better: If I can specify the needed code for a certain sheet name within the read.xls function. Then i only have to loop on all the files.

Thanks and let me know if you need some more information on this.

Comment: It may be easier to add additional sheets to a single workbook and create your desired structure by copying and pasting cell references.  Then those would be the sheets you import.  If the structures of the workbooks are identical, you could copy and paste with the macro recorder turned on for a single workbook. Then apply the code to all of the other workbooks.

Comment: Maybe that is a solution. I am also thinking of importing all files, inklusive sheets, into a list and simply subsetting the list elements I need into a dataframe

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem, by importing all excel files into a list, and then subsetting the nested lists (each column in each sheet). This works fine, as long as all files are identical. I believe that is the correct approach. I use purrr:map_chr to extract cell information.